# lo4j1.x to log4j2.x Programmatic way how to do?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2, underscore-java

I am trying to update my project from log4j1.2.17 to log4j2.17.

I am getting 3 errors while doing this migration.
I think we can do this using log4j.properties file or log4j.xml file or Programmatic way.
I must have to follow Programmatic way.

```
String fileName = logFilePath + Constants.FILENAME;

PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
layout.setConversionPattern(Constants.PATTERN);
DailyRollingFileAppender appender = new DailyRollingFileAppender(layout, fileName, Constants.DATE_PATTERN);
```

I am getting error in while changing dependency from 1.2.7 to 2.17 for log4j.
Anyone help how to fix this problem?

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-rolling-daily-file-example/

I took help from this website but its for log4j1.X version and I need log4j2.X code.

// Creates Pattern Layout
        PatternLayout patternLayoutObj = new PatternLayout();
        String conversionPattern = "[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n";
        patternLayoutObj.setConversionPattern(conversionPattern);
  
        // Create Daily Rolling Log File Appender
        DailyRollingFileAppender rollingAppenderObj = new DailyRollingFileAppender();

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments. Code is unreadable in comments. Also include the error you are getting.